# .NET HTTPClient Asynchronous Limitations

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I have a small .Net 4.5 C# app which reads information from a data source and then pushes this information to a web site which is a .NET 4.5 Web API site with a simple controller. The controller receives the data and puts it into a database.

The following works for me, as fast as the application can read it can write and everything ends up in the DB:

```
    public static void PostDataToWebApi(MyDataClass tData)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage s = null;

        try
        {
            s = client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/Station/Collector", tData).Result;
            s.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR (ClientPost): " + e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The following does NOT work. It POSTs about a thousand-odd records and then comes up with a number of errors all with the message "a task was canceled", but then after about 10 seconds it resumes processing:

```
    public static async void PostDataToWebApi(MyDataClass tData)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage s = null;

        try
        {
            s = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/Station/Collector", tData);
            s.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR (ClientPost): " + e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The full error is:

```
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
    at IICE_DataCollector_Remote.Program.<PostDataToWebApi>d__7.MoveNext() in e:\Users\TestUser.TEST\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test_App-trunk\TestCollector\Program.cs:line 475
```

Any quick fixes for this? From what I can tell it runs out of something, threads, sockets, who knows :-)

Any pointers would be appreciated, I'd love to get this working, as you can imagine doing the POST synchronously is considerably slower than asynchronously.

Just to be sure it wasn't my machine, local anti-virus or network I have tried on a W2k8 R2 server, a Windows 7 virtual guest desktop (fresh build) and a Windows 8 machine as well, with the same result.

**More Info** : I have tested this with partial success from a LAN connection with a smaller data set (10,000 records), and a DefaultConnectionLimit of 100. But, in production with 500,000 records, when posting to a remote server across the Internet (still low latency 25ms-50ms) I have not had any success.

Thanks in advance for any help :-)

Comment: What message for this exception?

Comment: Aren't you missing an `await` in your second version? It looks like it shouldn't even compile...

Comment: @JonSkeet you are correct, copy and paste error on my behalf! Have corrected this.

Comment: @CuongLe the message is "a task was canceled"

Comment: Did you set `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`?

Comment: @StephenCleary Nope, I'll check some code examples and give that a go. Any recommendations as to what limit I should set?

Comment: @Dominik: The default is 2, which is a very nice setting for public server access. Since this is your server, you can set it to whatever you deem acceptable (ideally leaving some breathing room, and remember that SQL Server usually doesn't scale as high as WebAPI). Once you experiment and find an appropriate setting, then you can use `SemaphoreSlim` on the client side to throttle your requests.

Comment: @StephenCleary  Just wondering if you have a code sample for SemaphoreSlim and HttpClient interactions like what I'm doing? I also found a ConcurrentQueue while going through MSDN, could always use that. The reason I ask is I have not had any luck adjusting the DefaultConnectionLimit. I've tried many different values between 8 and 200 with no success. Sometimes it errors quickly, sometimes it takes a bit longer, but the result is the same.

Comment: I meant to increase your `DefaultConnectionLimit` until your SQL Server instance cannot keep up anymore. Once you find that level, then subtract 20% or so for breathing room. Then take that value as your concurrency limit: initialize a `SemaphoreSlim` with that count, (asynchronously) acquire it before you call `PostAsJsonAsync`, and release it after you call `PostAsJsonAsync`.

Comment: The "a task was canceled" message from httpclient means it timed out (I think) and httpclient (even today) considers the wait time to include all time from when it was kicked off until it completes. So with a lot of requests the latter ones will time out. Increasing the connection limit helps because it increases the number of requests that get through before the timeout, but, if you have a very large number of requests you can still time them out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I have it working now. The biggest thing was to fine-tune the settings on the client end, for the server. These settings were different depending on whether I was running a test locally or over the Internet.

My "PostDataToWebApi" method now looks like this:

```
    public static async void PostDataToWebApi(MyDataClass tData)
        {

        await throttler.WaitAsync();
        allTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
        {

            try
            {
                var s = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/Station/Collector", tData).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR (ClientPost): " + e.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                throttler.Release();
            }
        }));
    }
```

I have the following declared at the top of my console application:

```
    private static List<Task> allTasks = new List<Task>();
    private static SemaphoreSlim throttler;
```

Before my loop starts I have the following, with the variables changed to make sure it all works:

```
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = _DefaultConnections;
    ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = _MaxIdleTime;
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;

    throttle = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: _MaxQueue);
```

As a guide, for an Internet based transaction the following works for me:

1. Default Connections : 24
2. Max Idle Time : 400
3. SemaphoreSlim Initial Count: 50

For my LAN test I could run both the default connections and the initial count values higher without a problem, which is to be expected I guess :-)

Finally, just outside my look I have the following to make sure I don't kill any tasks still running at the end of my execution run:

```
     await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the self-answer! It seems counterintuitive, but I found it important to have the semaphore initial count higher than the connection count as per the example settings. Otherwise the throughput was drastically reduced.