# HttpClient Scalability Problems?

Tags: asp.net, .net, httpclient

I have written this code inside of an ASP.NET application

```
public class MyClass {
    public static MyClass() {
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 64;
        ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 10000;
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
    }

    Public Task<string> DoQuery(string a) {
        using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler(){UseDefaultCredentials = true}))
        {
            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(MyWebAPI, new {A = a});
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string result = await.response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Initially this code runs fine. I can see that the web service is being called without problem but as more and more users hit my server ... suddenly I see lots of instances of this error in my log

```
   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 
Error while copying content to a stream. ---> System.IO.IOException: 
The read operation failed, see inner exception. ---> 
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
       at System.Net.ConnectStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Net.Http.DelegatingStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.WebExceptionWrapperStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
```

This reason why I am finding this problem very hard is because it does not appear initially but only when the server has become loaded it starts to come. Does this mean I am hitting some kind of limit with HttpClient?

Can you please help me out with this?

Edit:: I got the comment that the Web Service which is being called by this code might be erroring out and therefore I should check the web service. I wrote a load client and sent 6000 concurrent requests on the web service by multiple threads. The web service broke and clearly gave the error

```
Unable to connect to the remote server
An error occurred while sending the request.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SampleApp1.Program.<IsPermitted>d__1.MoveNext() in c:\myapps\SampleApp1\SampleApp1\Program.cs:line 58
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SampleApp1.Program.<IsPermitted>d__1.MoveNext() in c:\myapps\SampleApp1\SampleApp1\Program.cs:line 58
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
```

So if the web service was breaking down, then it would give the same error message to my code above ... which is not the case.

Also, my code above beings to error out only with a few requests (50 or 60) but the web service did not error out even with 5000 concurrent requests.... so I don't think its a web service problem.

Comment: Why are you calling Task.Run?  Why not await PostUsingClient()?

Comment: I searched for the same error message. one person had solved a problem similar to mine using this approach... but it did not help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120315/net-httpclient-asynchronous-limitations

Comment: even if I remove task.run and await on the PostUsingClient... its the same issue.

Comment: Well, you have a lot of problems here.. first, you're not cleaning up anything.. you should probably be wrapping those HttpClients in using statements, or calling Close and/or Dispose.  You've set a connection limit of 64, but you keep creating new clients which create new connections, but you never close the old ones.  Eventually, the garbage collector will run and close them, but who knows when that will be.

Comment: also, shouldn't PostUsingClient() be asyc as well?  and should you be awaiting in it?

Comment: I have updated my code above. the using statement was there... I had omitted it in the post above for brevity. Please have a look at corrected code.

Comment: You're still not awaiting on the PostAsJsonAsync

Comment: updated. sorry for typos. the code above is a sample created from the actual production code... so some of the pieces got missed out. I hope its OK now.

Comment: I would still remove the Task.Run... regardless, that's not the right thing to do, and instead await on it.  In fact, unless there's some reason, I would get rid of the PostUsingCLient method entirely, and just call PastAsJsonAsync direction, it doesn't add any value.

Comment: Also, probably not here or there.. but you shouldn't be setting all those servicepoint properties on each call.. they should be set once as they are static properties.. they should be configured once in an initialization method.

Comment: How do you know your service's endpoint is not hiccuping under load?

Comment: Actually, that's still likely to set those properties each time you create the class, unless you create the class only once.. I'd make the constructor static, or set them at the start of the application (assuming you never change these)

Comment: I have logging turn on my service end point and I can see debug statements appearing normally on the web end point. when the client gets a bunch of these errors I can go and recycle the web service but that does not solve the error on the client. so once the client starts getting this error...  it keeps on getting it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the stack trace, it appears that the problem may be more related to something on the other side.  The connection is being aborted on read, not on connect.  If you have access to the other side, you should check the logs or figure out what might cause it to cancel a send.

You could actually be running into a problem with ThreadPool exhaustion.  HttpClient, in general, doesn't use ThreadPool for Async I/O, but it does require ThreadPool to setup an Async I/O Send operation, and if you have a large number of requests all at once then it's possible you could be exhausting this pool.

Try Monitoring your applications ThreadPool usage via Performance Monitor and see what's happening.

The problem may also be related to persistent Http connections with Http Keep Alives.  You can try disabling them.

I also found at least one person who found that running the client in an ASP.NET application with Managed Pipeline mode in Classic mode caused this problem.  Changing to Integrated mode solved it for them.  Are you running in Integrated mode?

Comment: I wrote a console based test client which has the same HttpClient request and launced 6000 parallel threads to hammer the web service. when the web service could not take any load it said

Unable to connect to the remote server
An error occurred while sending the request.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()

Comment: However the code above errors out in 5 minutes with only 2 or 3 users. So it could not be the load on web service because then I will get the message above.

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch - Did you try any of my suggestions?

Comment: @eric made my constructor static. removed extra method and wait directly on PostAsJsonAsync

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch - I'm referring to the suggestions above about the threadpool, Keep Alives, and Integrated Mode.